# Swift filter array by condition

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

My Cat model has this:

```
var id: Int?
```

If I have an array of cats, how do I get all cats with a id of 7? I'm assuming I should use the filter method:

```
let filteredCats = cats.filter(???)
```

Comment: `cats.filter { $0.id == 7 }` ... although you can use the long version which Xcode will fill out for you, both work fine

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018365-filter filter is well documented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be simple until unless you don't have some other requirement.

```
cats.filter { $0.id == 7 }
```

And to skip optional values you can use `compactMap`

e.g

```
let array: [Cat] = [
    Cat(id: 7,   name: "CatA"),
    Cat(id: nil, name: "CatB"),
    Cat(id: 1,   name: "CatC"),
    Cat(id: 7,   name: "CatD"),
    Cat(id: 7,   name: "CatE"),
    Cat(id: 2,   name: "CatF"),
    Cat(id: nil, name: "CatG"),
]

print(array.compactMap { value -> Cat? in
    guard let id = value.id, id > 2 else { return nil }
    return value
})
```